# How can I remove the padding of a th when it's a vertical table header?

Tags: html, html-table, padding

I need to build something like a calendar but for one week. The problem is that I want to have some **vertical header** and some not. When I make vertical header, there is some additional padding. I can't remove it and I really found no solutions anywhere.

```css
.linkTableHeader {
   white-space:nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 5em;     
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.tableHeader {
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="height: 7em;">  
                        <th>
                            Elèves
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <a href="#">Lundi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            1
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            2
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            3
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            4
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            5
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            6
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            7
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <a href="#">Mardi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        </th>               
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <a href="#">Mercredi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <a href="#">Jeudi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <a href="#">Vendredi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <a href="#">Samedi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Comment: oh my god that looks so messed up

Comment: true ^^' 3 days on that shit already :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not what you want but, what if instead of rotating the entire cells, you rotate only the text? It would look better I suppose, even though I'd prefer the text to be horizontal, or rotated a few degrees and not 90.

```css
table{
    width: 700px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.linkTableHeader {
   white-space:nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.tableHeader {
    text-align: center;
}
.rotated {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="height: 7em;">  
                        <th>
                            Elèves
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                            <div class="rotated"><a href="#">Lundi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            1
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            2
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            3
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            4
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            5
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            6
                        </th>
                        <th class="tableHeader">
                            7
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                        <div class="rotated">
                            <a href="#">Mardi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
                        </th>               
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                        <div class="rotated">
                            <a href="#">Mercredi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                        <div class="rotated">
                            <a href="#">Jeudi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader">
                        <div class="rotated">
                            <a href="#">Vendredi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="linkTableHeader"><div class="rotated">
                            <a href="#">Samedi&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a></div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Comment: Yeah it's a bit better but i would the same width for the linkTableHeader and tableHeader

Comment: oh ok lemme change it a little

Comment: ok so I moved the `table-layout: fixed` attribute to the `table` tag, and then gave the table a certain width. This way, all cells have the same width, which I think was your problem.